# In R functions, print(some text) after return() statement

Tags: r, function, text, return

```
f <- function(x){
  print(paste0("x is: ",x))
  return(mean(rnorm(x))) #return() not neccessary
}
```

Then,

```
set.seed(8)
f(5)
```

Outputs:

```
[1] "x is: 5"
[1] 0.09550734
```

How can I get the print statement to appear after the result of the function, so the output would be:

```
[1] 0.09550734
[1] "x is: 5"
```

Can this be done in the same function without placing the text as part of the `return` arguments?

Comment: By definition, nothing in the function scope will be executed after a `return` call, so the answer to your question is, "you can't." Someone might be able to help you solve your actual problem though (i.e. why do you want to do this?) if you provide more details.

Comment: I have a relative large output when written to the screen, and would like to have a text statement in the end (a kind of summary of data). Perhaps then I should place the summary text in a list together with the output.

Comment: Just assign the result of the function and you got only the summary. In your example if you try `z<-f(5)`, the only thing that gets printed is `[1] "x is: 5"`. The return value of a function is only printed if you don't assign it to any variable. Alternatively, use `invisible`: `invisible(mean(rnorm(x)))` as last line of the function and the return value won't be printed.

Comment: Sure, but I actually want to have the option to have it printed to the screen. Think I must accept the function scope.

Comment: If so, try `res<-expressionThatGetsReturnValue;print(res);print(whateversummary);return(invisible(res))`. First you print the final value, then your summary and lastly return (invisibly) the value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change the function to return invisibly, and use `print` to show things in the order you want:

```
f <- function(x) {
  out <- mean(rnorm(x))
  print(out)
  print(paste("x is:", x))
  invisible(out)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
f <- function(x, print = TRUE){
# return(mean(rnorm(x))) #return() not neccessary
a <- mean(rnorm(x))
b <- paste(" x is:", x)
if isTRUE(print) {
    return(cat(c(a, b), sep = "\n"))
    }
return(x)
}
```